# What's the simplest way to extract the last section of an IP address?

Tags: c++-cli, text-parsing

I have an IP address which I want to grab the last chunk of as an integer. So from `"192.168.1.150"` I'd get `150`.

This is the code I'd concocted (I'm using C++/CLI), but somehow it feels rather clunky:

```
String^ ipString = "192.168.1.150";
int lastDot = ipString->LastIndexOf('.');
int lastSection = int::Parse(ipString->Substring(lastDot, ipString->Length-lastDot));
```

Is there a simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does that code really work? Shouldn't it read?:

```
int lastDot = ipString->LastIndexOf('.') + 1;
```

You don't have to specify the lengt to Substring if you want all that's left in the string, so you can shorten it to:

```
String^ ipString = "192.168.1.150";  
int lastSection = int::Parse(ipString->Substring(ipString->LastIndexOf('.') + 1) ;
```

Not much of an improvement though, but I doubt you can do much better.

Comment: You passed... and it's nice to know I've not missed anything obvious :-)

Comment: Of course, doing this is certainly a bug; what about the netmask?  If the network isn't a /24, that octet isn't unique.

Comment: I don't need a unique octet, just those last digits. I can't go into the specifics, but this is perfectly valid for my application.